# Script to open a website using a terminal automatically, remembering cookies

Tags: command-line, scripts, browser

Is there any way to make a script, which opens the URL with a minute interval, automatically, remembering old cookies?

It must be run from ssh, not always connected.

Answer (score -1):

New answer:

I make text only version of script what you may run in background easily, with help of `screen` or cron.

> Screen is better option for long running processes. Using screen you
>   can simply get the same session running on remote server even after
>   logout from ssh.

First start `screen`: $ screen

Run `elinks 'Yoursite'`. Manage login or anything else you want to affect cookies. Exit. Run my script in `screen`.

> Let’s detach your screen session with keyboard shortcut CTRL+a+d or
>   ctrl+alt+d. It will return you to command line. Now exit your ssh
>   session and again connect system through ssh and execute following
>   command to get old screen session running.
>
> $ screen -r

Script follows, I have test it on web mail to test cookies, all work fine, loggeg in once and stay logged in restarts of script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    elinks 'yandex.ru' &
    sleep 50s
    pkill -u "$(id -un)" elinks
    echo  "elinks killed, press ctrl-C to cancel loop. sleep 10s."
    sleep 10s
done
```

Note: elinks version from repo doesn't support javascript. Current version, if you build your self will support javascript if dependencies met.

Update: I have tested text only browsers `links` and `lynx`. First not remember cookies between sessions, second - I was unable to test it fully cause it doesn't allow to submit form may be because of javascript.(web mail was used to test, to see if I stay logged in on second browser run)

Comment: Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified, and i don't know how to use cookie with that

Comment: It should be run under X, then DISPLAY will be available, and cookie handled automatically by firefox

Comment: Great, but this idea must work even when I close the SSH connection

Comment: I will improve script. Do you able to get desktop(forwarding x for ssh) or other way? What else needed. May be killing old firefox on 50 seconds of 1 minute? It also possible to use text browsers but I don't known how they handle cookies between sessions, and don't support many modern browser features.

Comment: of course, I'm able.